# Application Unexpected error Encountered

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx

So I am creating a pretty simple application using DirectX in Visual Studio 2012.  Errors are gone according to what VS is telling me.  I went to run the application with debugging and it gives me an error that says:

it just shows a white window with another window that says in the title, "Unexpected error encountered".  It has a red X and says "File:" next to it.

[image]
It then says D3DApplication.exe has triggered a breakpoint. I choose break and it shows this line of code.

```
if(SUCCEEDED(m_pD3DDevice->Clear(0, 0, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 2.0f, 0)))\
{   
    if(SUCCEEDED(m_pD3DDevice->BeginScene()))
    {
```

Anyone have any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: The importance of whether `m_pD3DDevice` holds a valid interface address is paramount to this defect.

Comment: I'm still very new to programming.  Could you say that in simpler terms for me please?

Comment: Try as I might, I'm pressed to say it any clearer than I did.

Comment: As @WhozCraig said, make sure that `m_pD3DDevice` is valid. Maybe show where you initialise it.